# Pygubu Text-widget count character

Tags: python, tkinter, pygubu

I am new to pygubu and have a special issue.
In order to have a "realtime" character-counter for a text-widget.

I need to call the `def text-widget-change():` everytime the user changes the text in the text-widget (id: msg_text).
The length should be display in the entry-widget (textvariable: sMsglength).

python 3.8.3
tkinter 8.6
pygubu 0.10.0

```
import tkinter as tk
import pygubu
class Application:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master=master
        #Create builder
        self.builder = builder = pygubu.Builder()
        #Load ui file
        builder.add_from_file('Message.ui')
        #Create a widget, using master as a parent
        self.mainwindow = builder.get_object('mainframe', master)

        #Connect callbacks
        builder.connect_callbacks(self)
  def text-widget-change:
        entry = self.builder.get_object('msg_text')
        w = entry.get(0.0,'end')
        c=0
        for k in w:
            if k==" " or k=="\n":
                continue
            c=c+1
        show_length = self.builder.get_variable('sMsglength')
        show_length.set(c)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #Start Menu GUI
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Application(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You've told us what you want but haven't explained why you can't achieve that. What do you need help with? Are you familiar with how to bind functions to key events? Do you know how to update the text on an element?

Comment: Hi Bryan, all i found online was to create a text-widget-class which will be called when the text is modified. Since the Tkinter-root is already a class, this would mean a class within a class and there is where i am getting lost. Checking the content of the text-widget for every key-event sounds a easy but like an overkill. Is there a way to check if the content of the textwidget was changed within the pygubu-class "Application"?